# Suppose $S$ is an infinite set, and let $T=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n \}$. Then, $S$ and $S \cup T$ have the same cardinality.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Can anyone check my proof?

Another way to prove: There is a function $f:S\to (S\cup T)$ that is one-to-one and onto.

We will prove this in cases. The cases are:

1. $S$ is a countably infinite set, and
2. $S$ is an uncountably infinite set.

We will start with case 1. In this case, $S$ can be expressed as a sequence of distinct terms as $\{p_1, p_2, p_3,..., p_n\}$. The function  $f:S\to (S\cup T)$ is then given by $f(p_v)=x_v for v=1,2,3,...,n$ and $f(a_v)=a_{v+n}$ for all $v \geq n+1$ which is then a one-to-one and onto. Thus, we know  $S$ and $(S\cup T)$ which completes case 1.

We will now move on to case 2. We will stat by choosing some countably infinite proper subset and call it $Z$ of $S$. Then, from case 1, we get there is a bijection we will call $g$ such that $g:Z\to Z \cup T$. We can then use the identity function that $I:(S-Z)\to (S-Z)$ which then proves a bijection and completes case 2. Thus, the function $f$ is $g(x) if x\in Z$ and $I(x)$ if $x\in S-Z$ and is a bijection since $S$ and $S\cup T$ have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems fine.  Do you know yet about uncountable ordinals?  It turns out (using the Axiom of Choice) that you can list **any** infinite set $S = \{ s_{\alpha} \mid \alpha \lt \kappa \}$, where $\vert S \vert = \kappa$, the (possibly uncountable) cardinality of $S$.  Then just use the same proof:  Define $f: S \cup T \to S$ via $f(t_n) = \alpha_n, f(s_k)=s_{k+N}$ (where $T= \{ t_0, t_1, \ldots t_{N-1} \}$), and $f(s_\alpha)=s_\alpha$ for $\omega \leq \alpha$.